# bsp crashes in java

Tags: java, 3d

I wrote a [bsp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) function in java, and it always seems to crash in the same line of code, after about some thousands of iteration and it is actually the first line in the function:

```
if (!tri.isEmpty()) {
             Triangle3D t= tri.get(0);
```

the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
        at pythagorastree3d.Scene.BSP(Scene.java:100)
```

and i'm really sure that i wrote the function correctly.
can some one help me?

```
ArrayList<Triangle3D> tri = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();
    if (cubeOrSphere) {
        for (int i = 0; i < p.getBinTree().toArrayList().size(); i++) {
            tri.addAll(p.getBinTree().toArrayList().get(i).getTriangles());
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ps.getBinTree().toArrayList().size(); i++) {
            tri.addAll(ps.getBinTree().toArrayList().get(i).getTriangles());
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ks.length; i++) {
        tri.addAll(ks[i].getList());
    }
    //left-front, right-behind
    BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> bsp = new BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>>(new ArrayList<Triangle3D>());
    BSP(bsp, tri);


 private void BSP(BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> bsp, ArrayList<Triangle3D> tri) {
    if (!tri.isEmpty()) {
         Triangle3D t= tri.get(0);
        ArrayList<Triangle3D> front, back, on;
        on = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();
        on.add(t);
        front = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();//i.e. left
        back = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();//i.e. right
        Vector3D v;
        Triangle3D triangle;
        Vector3D intersection1, intersection2;

        for (int i = 1; i < tri.size(); i++) {
            v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP1().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP1().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP1().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
            if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 in front of plane
                v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP2().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP2().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP2().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 & p2 in front of plane 
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {//p1 & p2 & p3 in front of plane or on plane
                        front.add(tri.get(i));
                    } else {//p1 & p2 in front of plane p3 behind plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    }
                } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {// p1 in front of plane p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 & p3 in front of plane p2 behind plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP2());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection2, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {//p1 in front of plane p2 & p3 behind plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP1());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP1());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection2, intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else {// p1 in front of plane p2 behind plane p3 on plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP1());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    }
                } else {//p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {//p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane p3 in front or on plane
                        front.add(tri.get(i));
                    } else {//p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane p3 behind plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    }
                }
            } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {// p1 behind plane
                v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP2().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP2().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP2().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {// p1 behind plane p2 in front of plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {// p1 behind plane p2 & p3 in front of plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP1());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP1());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection2, intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {//p1 & p3 behind plane p2 in front of plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP2());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection2, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else {//p1 behind plane p2 in front of plane p3 on plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP1());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    }
                } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {//p1 & p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 & p2 behind plane p3 in front of plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3());
                        intersection2 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection2, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, intersection2, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) <= 0) {//p1 & p2 behind plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(tri.get(i));
                    }
                } else {//p1 behind plane p2 on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 behind plane p2 on plane p3 in front of plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else {//p1 behind plane p2 on plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(tri.get(i));
                    }
                }
            } else {//p1 on plane
                v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP2().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP2().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP2().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 on plane p2 in front of plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {//p1 on plane p2 in front of plane p3 in front or on plane
                        front.add(tri.get(i));
                    } else {//p1 on plane p2 in front of plane p3 behind plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    }
                } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {//p1 on plane p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 on plane p2 behind plane p3 in front of plane
                        intersection1 = intersectionPlane(t, tri.get(i).getP2(), tri.get(i).getP3());

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), intersection1, tri.get(i).getP3(), tri.get(i).col);
                        front.add(triangle);

                        triangle = new Triangle3D(tri.get(i).getP1(), tri.get(i).getP2(), intersection1, tri.get(i).col);
                        back.add(triangle);
                    } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) <= 0) {//p1 on plane p2 behind plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(tri.get(i));
                    }
                } else {//p1 & p2 on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(tri.get(i).getP3().getX() - t.getP1().getX(), tri.get(i).getP3().getY() - t.getP1().getY(), tri.get(i).getP3().getZ() - t.getP1().getZ());
                    if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {//p1 & p2 on plane p3 in front of plane
                        front.add(tri.get(i));
                    } else if (t.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {//p1 & p2 on plane p3 behind plane
                        back.add(tri.get(i));
                    } else {//p1 & p2 & p3 on plane
                        on.add(tri.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bsp.getInfo().addAll(on);
        if (!front.isEmpty()) {
            bsp.setLeft(new BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>>(new ArrayList<Triangle3D>()));
            BSP(bsp.getLeft(), front);
        }
        if (!back.isEmpty()) {
            bsp.setRight(new BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>>(new ArrayList<Triangle3D>()));
            BSP(bsp.getRight(), back);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your stacktrace itself is showing something fishy on line 100 of Scene Java class.

Comment: by relevant code you mean the whole bsp function? it's too long for a comment...
and line 100 is the line i pasted here.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code to debug by sight.

Comment: All the tri.get(i)'s make my eyes hurt. You should store the value in a temporary variable

Comment: ok, i changed it but now the recursion is infinite

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bother to check, if the implementation of algorithm is correct, but here's a cleaned up version of your code that uses while loop instead of recursive call:

```
private void BSP(BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> bsp,
        ArrayList<Triangle3D> triangles) {
    if (triangles.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    // Add work item
    Stack<BSPWorkItem> bspWorkItems = new Stack<BSPWorkItem>();
    bspWorkItems.add(new BSPWorkItem(bsp, triangles));

    while (!bspWorkItems.isEmpty()) {
        // Get work item
        BSPWorkItem bspWorkItem = bspWorkItems.pop();
        triangles = bspWorkItem.getTriangles();
        bsp = bspWorkItem.getBSP();

        Iterator<Triangle3D> triangleIterator = triangles.iterator();

        Triangle3D pivotTriangle = triangleIterator.next();
        // left
        ArrayList<Triangle3D> front = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();
        // right
        ArrayList<Triangle3D> back = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();
        ArrayList<Triangle3D> on = new ArrayList<Triangle3D>();
        on.add(pivotTriangle);

        while (triangleIterator.hasNext()) {
            Triangle3D currentTriangle = triangleIterator.next();
            Vector3D v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP1().getX()
                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle.getP1()
                    .getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(), currentTriangle
                    .getP1().getZ() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
            if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                // p1 in front of plane
                v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP2().getX()
                        - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                        .getP2().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                        currentTriangle.getP2().getZ()
                                - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                    // p1 & p2 in front of plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {
                        // p1 & p2 & p3 in front of plane or on plane
                        front.add(currentTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 & p2 in front of plane p3 behind plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D front2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, intersection2,
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(front2Triangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    }
                } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                    // p1 in front of plane p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 & p3 in front of plane p2 behind plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D front2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(front2Triangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                        // p1 in front of plane p2 & p3 behind plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);

                        Triangle3D back2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP3(), intersection2,
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(back2Triangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 in front of plane p2 behind plane p3 on plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    }
                } else {
                    // p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {
                        // p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane p3 in front
                        // or on plane
                        front.add(currentTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 in front of plane p2 is on plane p3 behind
                        // plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    }
                }
            } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                // p1 behind plane
                v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP2().getX()
                        - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                        .getP2().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                        currentTriangle.getP2().getZ()
                                - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                    // p1 behind plane p2 in front of plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 behind plane p2 & p3 in front of plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D front2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP3(), intersection2,
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(front2Triangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                        // p1 & p3 behind plane p2 in front of plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);

                        Triangle3D back2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(back2Triangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 behind plane p2 in front of plane p3 on plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    }
                } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                    // p1 & p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 & p2 behind plane p3 in front of plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());
                        Vector3D intersection2 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                intersection2, currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);

                        Triangle3D back2Triangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, intersection2,
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(back2Triangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 & p2 behind plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(currentTriangle);
                    }
                } else {
                    // p1 behind plane p2 on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 behind plane p2 on plane p3 in front of plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(frontTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 behind plane p2 on plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(currentTriangle);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // p1 on plane
                v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP2().getX()
                        - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                        .getP2().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                        currentTriangle.getP2().getZ()
                                - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                    // p1 on plane p2 in front of plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) >= 0) {
                        // p1 on plane p2 in front of plane p3 in front or
                        // on plane
                        front.add(currentTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 on plane p2 in front of plane p3 behind plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                intersection1, currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    }
                } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                    // p1 on plane p2 behind plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 on plane p2 behind plane p3 in front of plane
                        Vector3D intersection1 = intersectionPlane(
                                pivotTriangle, currentTriangle.getP2(),
                                currentTriangle.getP3());

                        Triangle3D frontTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.getP3(),
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        front.add(frontTriangle);

                        Triangle3D backTriangle = new Triangle3D(
                                currentTriangle.getP1(),
                                currentTriangle.getP2(), intersection1,
                                currentTriangle.col);
                        back.add(backTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 on plane p2 behind plane p3 behind or on plane
                        back.add(currentTriangle);
                    }
                } else {// p1 & p2 on plane
                    v = new Vector3D(currentTriangle.getP3().getX()
                            - pivotTriangle.getP1().getX(), currentTriangle
                            .getP3().getY() - pivotTriangle.getP1().getY(),
                            currentTriangle.getP3().getZ()
                                    - pivotTriangle.getP1().getZ());
                    if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) > 0) {
                        // p1 & p2 on plane p3 in front of plane
                        front.add(currentTriangle);
                    } else if (pivotTriangle.getNormal().dotProduct(v) < 0) {
                        // p1 & p2 on plane p3 behind plane
                        back.add(currentTriangle);
                    } else {
                        // p1 & p2 & p3 on plane
                        on.add(currentTriangle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        bsp.getInfo().addAll(on);
        if (!front.isEmpty()) {
            bsp.setLeft(new BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>>(
                    new ArrayList<Triangle3D>()));
            bspWorkItems.push(new BSPWorkItem(bsp.getLeft(), front));
        }
        if (!back.isEmpty()) {
            bsp.setRight(new BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>>(
                    new ArrayList<Triangle3D>()));
            bspWorkItems.push(new BSPWorkItem(bsp.getRight(), back));
        }
    }
}

private static class BSPWorkItem {
    private final BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> bsp;
    private final ArrayList<Triangle3D> triangles;

    public BSPWorkItem(BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> bsp,
            ArrayList<Triangle3D> triangles) {
        this.bsp = bsp;
        this.triangles = triangles;
    }

    public BinTreeNode<ArrayList<Triangle3D>> getBSP() {
        return bsp;
    }

    public ArrayList<Triangle3D> getTriangles() {
        return triangles;
    }
}
```

Comment: the while loop is also infinite

Comment: It's impossible to fix the algorithm without having the source code for all the relevant classes and a proper test case

Comment: I wrote what the application does before it call the BSP function